# In the mail header, what does the "received from" ip refer to?

Tags: smtp, email-server

I noticed that some mail header contact a field called `received : from`  and it contains an ip address.

Does this address refer to the sender machine even if he is using a web interface or to the server ?

Comment: I find this very helpful: https://www.pobox.com/helpspot/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=253

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mail starts at a client, this client sends it to the server. If the server has to hand it over to another server (because itself is not serving mail for the domain where the mail needs to go), it forwards it to the server that does. This server then adds `received : from` to the header.

Example:

bart@mydomain.com wants to send an email to sohaibafifi@yourdomain.com.

Bart creates an email and hands it to the mail server for mydomain.com. This server looks at the destination-address and sees it is `yourdomain.com`. This server does not provide mail for `yourdomain.com`. It has to look up the server that does via the MX Records for `yourdomain.com` and then forward the mail to it.

When the mail server for `yourdomain.com` has received the mail, he adds `received : from mail.mydomain.com` and delivers it to `sohaibafifi`'s mailbox or gives it to another server if this would be needed.

Example of such a chain:

```
Received: by 10.42.195.134 with SMTP id ec6csp80279icb;
        Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:45:09 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.180.103.42 with SMTP id ft10mr929660wib.18.1340091908492;
        Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:45:08 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from barracuda2.infraxnet.be (mail2.infraxnet.be. [78.24.168.38])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id c73si24136496wec.20.2012.06.19.00.45.07;
        Tue, 19 Jun 2012 00:45:08 -0700 (PDT)
```

You should read these bottom to top.

Comment: To be specific about one of his questions: no, the user's PC will not be in those headers if he's using webmail. And, beware that e-mail providers might not include the header. Gmail for instance is such a provider.

Comment: @Halfgaar: Are you sure Google does not includes these headers? Just had a look and they where there :)

Comment: Hmm, I can't find anything about it now. I could have sworn that was the case.

Comment: Of course, those headers can be easily faked, suggesting a provenance that didn't really exist.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Bart De Vos is saying even the first mail server that receives the message ie the home server of your organization will add a Received: from header indicating the client that is sending the message. In the case of a web interface into mail (webmail) the client sending the message is the server hosting the WebMail application. Usually both the IP address and the name of the client are recorded but it is possible to only record the IP address if the name (DNS) cannot be discovered. For example my server (postfix) records this like this

```
Received: from [10.16.16.63] (client.inmydomain [10.16.16.63]) .....
```

Essentially, as a result of the above a message can be traced back to its source this way and the route (relays) that it has traversed. Mind you though that there are ways to modify these records.

Answer (score 1):

I just did the test for you:

I first sent an email from my outlook to my gmail and then from the hotmail webinterface. This is the result:

From my outlook:

```
Received: from 20.20-200-80.adsl-dyn.isp.belgacom.be (HELO jameson) ([80.200.20.20])
  by relay.skynet.be with ESMTP; 19 Jun 2012 09:45:24 +0200
```

From hotmail:

```
Received: from BAY162-W38 ([65.54.190.201]) by bay0-omc4-s7.bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
```

As you can see when I'm sending the email from the hotmail webinterface, the IP from my computer is not included.

Comment: can you please test it with yahoo ? it seems that even using the webmail, yahoo send the machine ip !

Comment: you can just test that yourself, you are a student, you need to learn how to explore :)